# Represent versioned-number in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 installed on my laptop and my database contains a versioned-number which has this format : A.B.C.D ( example : 1.2.13.6 ). How can i apply MAX aggregation to my column "version" which is text. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are **always** numeric, you can do something like this:

```
select max(string_to_array(version, '.')::int[])
from your_table;
```

By converting the string into an array of integers, the comparison will be done correctly `[1,12,1]` is bigger than `[1,1,1]`

This will however fail if you have values like `1.2.13.6a` in that column

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4608

Comment: Which data should version be to be taken in string _to_array because it refuses text. Thank you

Comment: ERROR:  cannot cast type text[] to integer
LINE 1: select max(string_to_array(driver_version, '.')::int)

Comment: @TheAnswer Just add `[]` like `)::int[])`

Comment: @TheAnswer: `version` is expected to be `text`. But I did forget the `[]` as clodoaldo noticed.